# GPS autonomous robot

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming, c++, c

I am working on a GPS autonomous robot using Arduino, HMC5883 compass, Adafruit GPS module and I have managed to sort of complete the coding for it and I tried compiling / verifying it and I get an error. It would be helpful if anyone could assist help me find out what I am doing wrong in my code as I have spent 2 days looking for what I have done wrong and if someone could suggest a better way of writing my code or even improving it here code I appreciate it. HERE IS MY CODE http://textuploader.com/drhfa

Error:

```
GPS_move_:468: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "radians"
```

Comment: I assume the problem is with this line: `Wire.send("A);`

Comment: it's not that I just corrected it and it still comes up with the error-@gre_gor

Comment: There's numerous missing semicolons...

Comment: Also you seem to have a missing close bracket at `differencelongitude = radians((longitudeWaypoint2 - (longitudeWaypoint1));` (or an excess open bracket)

Comment: And a colon instead of a semicolon here: `turn_left():`

Comment: Using autoformat helps to highlight where these kind of problems are since the formatter can't format it right if there are errors like this.

Comment: Please post the code.  the linked location says the post has expired..   Suggest posting the code as part of your question (indent all code 4 spaces, so it will be displayed as code.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot compile because there are libraries missing. However, after auto-formatting the code I have this list of problems:

- Many lines lack semicolons at the end (check your variable definitions near the top of the code)
- You have an extra bracket in one of your `radians()` calls (the one that is giving the error I guess): `differencelongitude = radians((longitudeWaypoint2 - (longitudeWaypoint1));`
- There is an unterminated string literal: `Wire.send("A);`
- You have a colon instead of a semicolon: `turn_left():`

There may be more but as I cannot even begin to compile I cannot find them easily - also there may be similar errors in any included files you have created.